# Jenkins Groovy Pipeline - Pull all text files from a directory into a List

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

Trying to obtain a list of all text files in the given directory within my Jenkins pipeline job. I'm receiving an error that the file cannot be found. However, this code executes fine when I try it in groovy, outside of the Jenkins. Error received:

> java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   C:\temp\jenkins\workspace\pollandExecute_new\swqa_git

I've confirmed that a file is present in the location and that the folder and files have full control rights in Windows.

```
    def list = []

    // Obtain all text files within the specified directory
    def folder = "C:\\temp\\jenkins\\workspace\\pollandExecute_new\\swqa_git"
    new File(folder).eachFileMatch(~/.*.txt/) {file -> list << file}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured it out. The problem is that the code is looking at the local directory on my Jenkins box and NOT the local dir of the actual host which I'm attempting to execute the job on.